# React with React-router: do I render everything from the top then show/hide depending on route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Confused: single-page app: page1 is initially displayed, has a button to switch to page two.

Should the main render in App be:

```
return {
<div>
    <page1/>
    <page2/>
</div>
}
```

Then use state to determine whether a page is show/hidden?

Or does it render page2 due to the route? I figure because the state gets changed in the onclick of the button on page1 to reflect the new 'currentPage' then the main App will automatically get re-rendered.

Without react-router I think I understand: but with routes I seem to be confusing myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router deals with showing views based on the URL. If the button doesn't change the URL (e.g. it only changes some internal state), you would use the state in `App` to conditionally render either `Page1` or `Page2`.

However, if the URL should decide if `Page1` or `Page2` should be rendered, you would set this up in the React Router configuration, and you would not manually render either one of them (React Router would automatically decide what to render for you). The button would then simply link to the new URL (via React Router's `<Link />` tag or via APIs on `this.context.router`) instead of changing state.

Comment: AH HA! Thanks that is precisely what I was confusing myself over. In case it matters I am using transitionTo after invoking a callback passed down from the main App to call setState. So the main App will re-render due to that, but the URL does in fact change.